# Merging all CMS proposals/sites into one?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Currently there are CMS sites for a number of popular Content Management Systems and even more proposals for other CMS sites. Would it not be beneficial to the community to merge all CMS site into one single CMS site.

Stack Overflow could have easily been divided into individual sites for every programming language. Most of these sites would still have thrived, however, by keeping them all together it has achieved more then it ever could have if it divided them.

Would this not be true for CMS related Stack Overflow sites?

My reasoning is that a lot of developers use multiple Content Management Systems. These developers can answer questions related to a number of different Content Management Systems, but might only be active on one CMS site. Even though there are a lot of differences among Content Management Systems the core ideas are the same and they all share the same basic principle of managing content to be displayed on the internet. Programming questions about a CMS are better asked on Stack Overflow as it is focused on programming and you are more likely to get a good answer there.

It would benefit the CMS community to be merged because it would increase the 'available knowledge' of the community. It would also benefit smaller Content Management Systems that do not have a large enough following for their own site as it would give their users a place to ask questions.

Comment: You might want to move this to [Area 51 Discussions](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Each CMS is different, has different idioms and active community centered around it - why would joining them up be beneficial?

Comment: Added why I believe it to be beneficial and my reasoning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be better discussed with our CMS-based communities to see what *they* think.

But what would Stack Exchange look like if we bypassed the community-process of Area 51 and came up with our own site ideas; a series of logical subjects, neatly organized into their own Q&A sites?

Every time we tried to *will* a site into existence, it was a disaster.

The short answer is that we have individual support sites because that is what those communities wanted, and *they* made it happen. We did not build a generic CMS sites because **it was proposed… many, many times** and virtually nobody was interested. So those proposals failed.

You can't build a community if no one will show up.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I was not aware that a generic site was previously proposed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure because timeline of all the CMS sites are varied such as WordPress, Drupal, Joomla are relatively older sites with their own community base and there are several others such as Craft CMS, Sitecore which are in beta and or in there early phases.

And not all the CMS are purely CMS or have only programming-related questions. Some have installation- and maintenance-related questions too which pertains to their specific version.

And this question somewhat belongs to [Area 51 discussion zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You have posed a question, but with no support. *Would it not be beneficial to the community to merge all CMS site into one single CMS site?* I don't see why. I think your reason to say so is your opinion that bigger communities are always better. That is not true.

Sites need a decent narrow scope, and with every CMS there is a clear scope to define. Just like combining all language sites could be possible, the language makes the scope of the site clear. As long as a site has enough traffic, enough active users and a narrow scope, it is okay. There is no need to merge sites then.

If all or most CMS-specific sites have problems with the amount of active users, the number of questions, etc., then it would be a reason for me to support merging all those sites together.