# Can we have a Blockchain community?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

Just a thought, I see that many questions arise with 'Blockchain' and to address that can we have separate community in the Stack Exchange network?

We do have a 'Bitcoin' community, can we make a Blockchain community in general?

If no, then please point me why we should avoid it?

Comment: related discussion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301373/369802

Comment: The Bitcoin SE narrowed its scope to questions about technologies that are applicable to Bitcoin in the summer of 2019. You can read more here: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/5406

Answer (score 6):

When this question was asked, the answer was simple: despite its name, Bitcoin Stack Exchange used to accept questions about [alternative blockchains](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternatives), i.e. blockchains other than the ones being used for cryptocurrencies.

Example questions:

- [Does it make sense to design a mutable blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/77313/42185)
- [can I use elements of the blockchain to protect the integrity of a leaderboard without central servers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/45908/42185)

However, this is **no longer the case**, as @ThorkilVærge pointed out in a comment: [Proposal: Narrow topic of Bitcoin.Stackexchange to questions applicable to Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/42185).

The time may be right to start a new Blockchain proposal on Area 51, as e.g. mentioned [here on Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32290/151554) by user @MaartenBodewes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question notes:

> We do have a 'Bitcoin' community,

and asks:

> can we make a Blockchain community in general?

You could go to the Meta of the [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) and try to convince that community to re-brand as the Blockchain Stack Exchange, but I suspect the path of least resistance will be to simply ask your Blockchain questions at the [Bitcoin Stack Exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) where [@Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316807/215590) notes that they are already on-topic.