# Why have multiple StackExchange sites for Cryptocurrencies

Tags: discussion

I wonder why there is a site for single cryptocurrencies (e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

In my opinion it would be more helpful to have a single StackExchange site like *cryptocurrency.stackexchange.com* with different tags for different cryptocurrencies (e.g. Bitcoin, Ethereum, Ripple, Litecoin, etc.)

---

#### Current state

Let's take programming languages as an example. When using the same structure as currently used for cryptocurrencies we would have a single stackexchange site for each programming language (e.g. *java.stackexchange.com*, *python.stackexchange.com*) but instead we have a single site https://stackoverflow.com where all programming questions are asked with different tags for different languages.

#### New cryptocurrency/programming language

For new languages we only need a new tag and users can start asking questions for this specific programming languages. For cryptocurrencies instead you need to wait for a new stackexchange site, which may, for small cryptocurrencies, never appear. If there was a single site for all cryptocurrencies though, you could just ask that questions under a new tag.

#### General questions

And what about questions regarding cryptocurrencies (or programming) in general? On Stackoverflow we can simply ask those questions by not using language- but topic-specific tags. For cryptocurrencies you would *?probably?* have to post them under https://crypto.stackexchange.com using the `crypocurreny` tag, which is, in my opinion, weird and not good structured, also because there are a lot of different topics regarding cryptocurrencies which currently can't be differentiated because there is only one tag `cryptocurreny` available.

Comment: Related: [What is the point of having different sites for each service in the same or similar domain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301373/295232)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to first search for it but didn't find something. Maybe I used the wrong keywords to search.