# Where can I ask cryptocurrency or blockchain questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

There seems to be a plethora of places where you can ask cryptocurrency and blockchain (distributed ledger, mining etc.) related questions on Stack Exchange. However, there doesn't seem to be a comprehensive list of where to ask a particular question. Can we create a wiki post that anybody can edit which points users in the right direction?

Comment: Related: *[What is the point of having different sites for each service in the same or similar domain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301373/what-is-the-point-of-having-different-sites-for-each-service-in-the-same-or-simi)*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Stack Exchange network currently has 9 active sites where you can ask questions related to a specific type/ variant of cryptocurrency or related technology (sites marked with <sup>beta</sup> are in active beta):

- [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com)
- [Cardano](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/)
- [EOS.IO](https://eosio.stackexchange.com)
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com)
- [IOTA](https://iota.stackexchange.com)
- [Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com)
- [Stellar](https://stellar.stackexchange.com)
- [Substrate and Polkadot](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/) <sup>beta</sup>
- [Tezos](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/)

<sup>[Augur](https://augur.stackexchange.com) was a related, proposed Stack Exchange site that ran in beta for a little over a year before closing for lack of activity. It no longer accepts new content or interactions.</sup>

Note that, currently, there are **no** Stack Exchange sites for generic cryptocurrency or blockchain related questions. However, there are sites in the Stack Exchange network beyond those listed above that allow questions related to cryptocurrency when they are also on-topic for the respective site.

Questions that are related to the following topics may be asked on the following sites:

- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com); if the question is related to the technology used by the blockchain or for mining (etc.).
- [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com); if the question is related to the cryptographic algorithms and protocols used *within* the blockchain/ mining (etc.).
- [Personal finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com); if the question is about the impact of cryptocurrency on your personal finances (and is otherwise [on-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); note that questions asking for service provider recommendations or specific buy/ sell advice are off-topic).
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/); if the question is about a specific programming problem relating to a technology involved with the blockchain or other cryptocurrency mechanisms.

**While each Stack Exchange site is moderated to the best of the respective community's ability, please be vigilant of scams in cryptocurrency spaces.** This includes any of the mentioned Stack Exchange sites, as well as any resource you encounter on cryptocurrencies in general.

You can e.g. type `[bitcoin.se]` or `[ethereum.se]` in comments and chat and it will expand the name and provide a link to the indicated site.

*Please do not ask for help recovering your wallet on any of these sites. Stack Exchange is not created to provide personal help; we can only provide generic answers.*

There are also many other forums that allow users to post questions on this and related topics, for instance:

- [Reddit CryptoTechnology subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoTechnology/)
- [Reddit CryptoCurrency subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/)
- [Reddit CryptoMarkets subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoMarkets/)
- [Quora Crypto-Blockchain (Cryptocurrency news) space](https://cryptoblockchain1.quora.com/?q=%23crypto)

For a (possibly negatively biased) up-to-date survey of web3, cryptocurrencies, blockchains, smart contracts, NFTs, and the like, there's [Web3 is going just great](https://web3isgoinggreat.com/). It's not a Q&A site, though.

Comment: This was made a community wiki for a reason, please keep this post up to date or adjust if anything is amiss by hitting [edit]!

Comment: A relevant Area 51 Discussions announcement from this past March: [Area 51 is no longer allowing individual blockchain, cryptocurrency, or web3 proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32746/192942)